# Hibernate updating child entities while updating parent entity

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, annotations, hibernate-mapping

I have two entities as User and Projects having @ManyToMany relationship between them as follows.

**Entity Classes**

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column (name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column (name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column (name = "password")
        private String password;
    @Column (name = "last_login")
    private Date lastLogInDate; 
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,CascadeType.MERGE})
        @JoinTable(name = "project_assigned", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id")  }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_project_id") } )
    private Set<Projects> projects = new HashSet<Projects>(0);  

    // setter and getter methods.
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Projects {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column (name = "name")
    private String name;    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_projects", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_project_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id") })
    private Set<User> userSet = new HashSet<User>(0);   

}
```

**DAO Class**

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO {

    public User findByCredentials(String email, String password) {
        String queryString = " from User u where u.email = ? and u.password = ?";
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);
        query.setString(0, email);
        query.setString(1, password);       
        return (User) query.uniqueResult();     
    }

    public boolean updateUser(User user) {
        boolean result = true;
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            session.update(user);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            result = false;
            logger.error("Can not Update User"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return result;
    }           
}
```

**Service Class**

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true,propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public User findByCredentials(String userName, String lastName) {
        return userDAO.findByCredentials(userName, lastName);   
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public boolean updateUser(User user) {
        return userDAO.updateUser(user);
    }
}
```

**Other Code**

```
User user = userService.findByCredentials("xyz@pqr.com", "abc");
user.setLastLogInDate(new Date());
userService.updateUser(user);
```

My problem is that when I am updating the 'LastLogInDate' of an User 
then all Project Entities assigned to that user are getting updated (unnecessary fire update statement)
due to this my application performance is low. How can I solve this problem. and how can I do this in better way. Thanks for your help.

Here is my SQL logs

```
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL#log  - update users set email=?, password=?, last_login=? where id=?
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL#log  - update user_projects set name=? where id=?
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL#log  - update user_projects set name=? where id=?
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL#log  - update user_projects set name=? where id=?
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL#log  - update user_projects set name=? where id=?
DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL#log  - update user_projects set name=? where id=?
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

you must set your cascade since cascade can't be set during runtime (save):

```
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,CascadeType.MERGE})
```

you must at least remove the `CascadeType.MERGE`. because MERGE means something complex that approximates "save" but is more like "push this detached entity back into managed status and save its state changes". the cascading means that all associated entities get pushed back the same way, and the managed-entity handle you get back from .merge() has all managed entities associated with it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have made changes as per your suggestion and I have changed **@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,CascadeType.MERGE})** to **@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})** but it not works

Answer (score -1):

Remove all cascade options. This will solve your problem

1 solutions:

Solution 1:

USer class:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_projects", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_project_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id") })
private Set<Projects> projects;
```

Projects Class

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "user_projects", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_project_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id") })
private Set<User> userSet;
```

Comment: This should be posted as a comment and not as an answer. Please remove.